# Convert struct to list

Tags: python-polars

I have a problem of converting a struct column to a list column.

Specifically, I'm using splitn to split a string column in a dataframe by a delimiter n number of times. I want to reverse split (rsplit in Python) that string and hence want to convert it to a list so I can use .list.reverse().

Is it really correct that I cannot convert a struct to a list?

Here's an example of what I want. I have

```
df = data.with_columns(
    [
        pl.col("onboarded_date")
        .str.splitn("/", 2)
        .struct.rename_fields(["column1", "column2"])
        .alias("fields")

    ]
)
```

That gives me a column with a struct. If I use unnest, I "expand"/flatten to separate columns. I would like to **A)** be able to reverse the struct before unnest'ing (which is similar to [rsplit](https://www.w3schools.com/python/ref_string_rsplit.asp) in Python) and **B)** explode the struct so as to generate rows instead of columns (which is possible with a list, see below):

```
out = data.with_columns(
    [
        pl.col("onboarded_date")
        .str.split("/")
        .alias("fields")
    ]
).explode("fields")
```

The problem of the above is that split (as opposed to splitn which I want) returns a list, not a struct.

I have tried struct.to_list() which works when its the opposite (i.e. list.to_struct). That doesn't work.

Comment: There is no struct to list function currently, perhaps it's worth a feature request. If you show an actual code example of what you're trying to do, I imagine there'll be an alternative solution.

Comment: @jqurious I added an example in the question

Comment: Ok - thanks. Can you show an actual row example of `onboarded_date` (I guess it's a "1/2/3" string) and the output you want? It's not entirely clear (to me anyway) what the output should be.

Comment: It's for a function so the output can vary slightly based on the input arguments. 

onboarded_date is exactly as you say. Just a string column with / as a separator (could be 1/2/3). 

Let's say I would like to split by "/" with a max number of splits = 2 and split to rows.

In that case, I would get two rows from the original 1 row containing _1/2/3_ in onboarded_date. The first row would contain _1_ and the second row would contain _2/3_

Comment: Okay, well you can build a new list "manually" e..g `.with_columns(fields = pl.concat_list(pl.col("fields").struct["column2"], pl.col("fields").struct["column1"])` - An alternative could be to emulate the splitn with `.str.extract` e.g. `left = pl.col("onboarded_date").str.extract("([^/]+)"), right =  pl.col("onboarded_date").str.extract("/(.+)")`

Comment: How do you recon that impacts performance? Also, I don't know the number of splits meaning I don't know the columns in advance. I get around that by using the following `columnNames = []
        for i in range(columnsNumber):
            columnNames.append(column+"_"+str(i))`. Imagine columnsNumber hold the number of splits and column is the column to split.

Comment: I'm not sure I follow - if one is using splitn - then the number of splits must be known? You're supposed to be able to extract fields by number e.g. `.struct[n]` but it appears that needs to be fixed. https://github.com/pola-rs/polars/issues/10096

Comment: Sorry if this comes off as harsh or rude but this seems like the epitome of an [XY problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem). Firstly, you're splitting strings which are a date (column is onboard_date) so why not just use `to_date`? Secondly, your question is how to convert a struct to a list but, in the context of using `split` instead of `splitn`, you say that you want a struct not a list which contradicts the whole question. Take a step back from split, splitn, structs, and lists and just ask the thing you actually want.

Comment: No worries! Reg #1: onboarded_date is just an example. Its for a function that can take any column in a df, any delimiter, split to rows or columns and split right-to-left or left-to-right. I cannot handle splitting to rows with a struct (due to explode only applying to lists) and I can't reverse a struct either. Reg #2: does #1 address your concern? I never want a struct, but can work with it if I can turn it into a list. The difference in output between split and splitn/splitexact is not a problem - unless you can't utilize the same functionality on a struct as you can on a list.